# What’s the best way to load content in an iOS app?

Tags: swift, firebase, aws-sdk

I am working on an iOS wallpapers app that lets users explore interesting wallpaper images. I am not sure, however, what the best way to load the images is. I would be most comfortable with a server less approach, as I would not have to worry about server upkeep. However, this means I’d have to include all the images in the app package which would be very heavy and not easy to add new content. I assume I will need to go the server route but am looking for a push in the right direction as to which service I should use, how much it will cost, and if I can support millions of users out of the gate. I am comfortable with Firebase but am not sure if that is the best option. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case keeping static images in your app sounds like a bad idea, for the reasons you listed. For a small project using Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firstore along with the Storage module would probably be the safest approach.

If you haven't already check out the [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) (iOS) and [Piccaso](https://github.com/square/picasso)  (Android) libraries to handle the image downloads.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I have implemented Firebase and it is working well. Users will only be downloading the images from Firestore so i''m hoping Firebase prices won't be too crazy

Comment: No problem, glad it was useful.